# What's the fastest way to get started with Kohana PHP framework?

Tags: php, kohana

I have been reading that Kohana is good for my project. So now I want to get started. My PHP knowledge is 2 years old and very limited now. But I am experienced with object oriented programming and other patterns, since I develop in Objective-C. I know a little bit about databases.

People told me the Kohana documentation is horribly poor. So, where do I start as a newcommer?

Comment: If it really must be Kohana, read Kohana itself and start building something right away!

Answer (score 1):

this might not be the best way but
1. i watched the 2 tutorial videos on the codeignitor framework and tried a small example
2. i switched to kohana and tried the same thing and haven't looked back

i am quite familiar with php, so your mileage may vary

Answer (score 1):

You'll definately want to start from the Kohana 101 wiki.

[You may find it here.](http://dev.kohanaphp.com/wiki/kohana2/Kohana101)

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by petsagouris, the **[101 wiki](http://dev.kohanaphp.com/wiki/kohana2/Kohana101) is a good resource for seeing examples** of how to use the framework.  It's also worth **reading the docs** as well.  Even though they aren't as good as CI's they still contain a lot of useful information.

However if you want to get the most from the framework I recommend you **invest a couple of hours looking through the code** of the classes that you use (e.g. Kohana, ORM and if you're feeling brave, Database).

The files are very well documented and the experience will help you solve problems more quickly as you will know *how* Kohana works, and *where* to look if something isn't quite working as you expected.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid the pain of setting up the initial environment, I have released a vagrant dev environment with a base checkout of Kohana 3.3.1. Jumping right into the code is usually the best way to go. Hopefully this helps.

[Intro to Vagrant with Kohana and Zen Kommerce](http://blog.jamieisaacs.com/2014/03/04/intro-to-vagrant-with-kohana-and-zen-kommerce/)